# How to implement relationship in where condition Laravel's eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

1. Students
2. Results

The two tables have one to may relationship.

```
Student model:

public function results()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
    }
```

```
Result model:

public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
```

In the students table I have a field called `average_score`.

How can I execute the following query, this is not working it says "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$student":

```
$data = Result::with('student')->where('score', '>=', function($q){
        $average_score = $q->student->average_score;

        return $average_score;
})->get();
```

In order to get the results that are only higher or equal to than the "average_score".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to find those results:

```php
$data = Result::with('student')->whereHas('student', function($q) {
    $q->whereColumn('average_score', '<=', 'Results.score');
})->get();
```

Comment: `where` or `whereColumn` ?

Comment: Sorry, `whereColumn`, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If `score` and `average_score` are columns of the same table (`student`), try this;

```
$data = Result::with(['student' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereColumn('score', '>=', 'average_score');
    }])->get();
```

If `score` and `average_score` are columns of the different tables, try this;

```
$data = Result::with('student')->whereHas('student', function($q) {
        $q->whereColumn('students.average_score', '<=', 'results.score');
    })->get();
```

Comment: I don't think so, student has many results, and all those results have a avg_score for a student, so the avg score is the student's column.

Comment: I added an additional solution

Answer (score 0):

get value from column `Results.average_score` then compare to `student.score`:

```
Result::with([
        'student' => function($query) {
            $query->where("score",">=", "Results.average_score"););
        }
    ])
```